# Why ofstream::rdbuf() is always empty?

Tags: c++, optimization, ofstream

```
ofstream ofs1("file1.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

unsigned char data[64] = {0};
ofs1.write((char*) &data, sizeof(data));

if (some_condition)
{
    ofstream ofs2("file2.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    ofs2 << ofs1.rdbuf();// This does not work.
}

unsigned char more_data[32] = {1};
ofs1.write((char*) &more_data, sizeof(more_data));
```

As expected, *file1.dat* is 96 bytes in size after executing the code. However, *file2.dat* is 0 bytes, where I would expect it to be 64 bytes. Apparently `ofstream::rdbuf()` is always empty, or is it not supposed to be used like this?

Practical use for this: an application that writes several files using the same header (e.g. a colour palette). In this code example the contents of `data` (colour palette) are static, but it can obviously be replaced by a more complex computation, which would be overkill to repeat for each output file...

Comment: `This does not work.` it's an `ofstream`, the underlying buffer can't be read from.

Comment: But there must be some way to copy the buffer contents before it has been flushed?

Comment: @Midas : it is not intended to be read from. Mere existence of buffer and knowledge that there is content in it is implementation detail which should not be exposed. You can write your own wrapping buffer which will log info sent to it.

Comment: @Midas make it an `fstream` and open it with `ofs1.in | ofs1.out | ofs1.binary`, don't forget to seek to the beginning before reading.

Comment: @user657267 Already tried that, but doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Edit your question with exactly what you have tried.

Comment: Using `fstream` with `ios::in` added, I also tried `ofs1.flush()` before `rdbuf()`, but the file is still 0 bytes.

Comment: Show your code, if you aren't seeking to the beginning of the stream what do you expect to read?

Comment: @user657267 Exactly... If you post that as an answer I will accept it right away. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that an `ofstream` by default opens its buffer in output mode only, and either way you're only passing `std::ios_base::out`, which means the buffer cannot be read from.

To fix this you will need to switch to using an `fstream` and open it with `std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary`.

You will also need to seek to the start of the file before calling `rdbuf`by calling `seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg)`.